# Size of predefined/assigned char[], naming conventions, easily copying a struct and fetching function address with ampersand

Tags: c

1. How to find the size of a predefined char[] variable that holds a string?
   Should sizeof be enough?
   I don't want to use strlen() since a '\0' character may occur in the string, and for optimization reasons.
   E.g.: `char str[] = "Hello \x45\x10\x00 World!";`
2. What do you do when there're initials in the identifier? E.g. GetURLParameters().
   I thought of adding an underscore: GetURL_Parameters(). What is the convention for this situation?
3. How can I easily copy values to the fields of a struct that is pointed by a   variable/pointer?
   For example, I would like to do something similar to:

   ```
   struct {
   int         bar1;
   char*       bar2;
   callback    bar3;
   } *foo = NULL;
   foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
   *foo = { 0, "Hello World!", myFunc };   // This is wrong
   ```
4. Why programmers sometimes use an ampersand to assign an address of a function to a function pointer? E.g.:

   ```
   void (*callback)(void);
   callback = &myFunc;
   ```

   (Sorry, but I can't edit well my post. It looks different when I edit, and when it's shown to you)

Comment: I'm sorry but, we're not here to do other's homework

Comment: It's not homework, really. I can't see why you think that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If it's a `char[]` and not a `char *`, `sizeof()` will give you the array size (which is `strlen() + 1` for nul-terminated strings). If you need to work extensively with strings (especially ones that may have the `'\0'` character in them and/or may not be nul-terminated) you should consider using a string library. It will make your life much easier.
2. Whatever you want. I personally never use capital letters in identifiers, because I think `MixedCaseIdentifiers` are ugly. There is no convention for naming identifiers, only conventions that some people like. Use whatever looks best to you (and your team).
3. You can do this:

   ```
   struct s {
       int         bar1;
       char*       bar2;
       callback    bar3;
   };
   struct s *foo = NULL;
   static struct s default = { 0, "Hello, world!", myFunc };
   foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
   *foo = s;
   ```

   My standards-fu is failing me, so I'm not sure why this works (or even if it does absolutely) but I believe it does. If it doesn't work, you just need to make an `init` function that sets all the fields to their default values.
4. Consistency. When assigning an address to a pointer, it's normally necessary, i.e. `int i = 5, *j = &i;` so even though it's not strictly necessary for function pointers, some people like to do it so that all pointer assignments look the same. It's just aesthetics.

However, in the future, most of these questions are unrelated to each other. You shouldn't group four unrelated questions into one giant monster question, but instead ask them separately. It'll make you take more time for each one, and each will come out more coherently so we'll be able to give you better answers (and you'll learn more).

Comment: OK, thank you, I'm new here so I don't know all the unwritten rules. I thought that serially opening too many questions would be selfish or something.

Comment: @Chris Lutz - That code doesn't compile for me. I'm using g++ (the version bundled with cygwin, not sure on the exact version number). I think you need a cast on malloc, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @dcp: Why are you using g++ (and not gcc) on C code?  `malloc` doesn't need a cast in straight C.

Comment: The "casting `malloc()`" debate can go on and on, but in summary: If you need people to compile it with a C++ compiler, you have no choice and must cast. If you don't need this, you can cast if you want, but if you don't a) you will be warned if you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>` (with a cast it will silently fail, as `malloc()` has been given an implicit signature) and b) if the type changes later (say, from `char *` to `wchar_t *`) you don't need to go back and change all your casts (this is the same reason to use `sizeof *foo` instead of `sizeof(struct foo)`). The second is most compelling.

Comment: Note that `sizeof` will give the size of the array in *bytes*, not the number of elements.  For arrays of `char`, this is the same thing, but for other types it is not.  For an array of type T, where T is not char, the number of *elements* is given by `sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]`.

Comment: @John Bode - This is true. Ideally there would be a macro `#define ARR_LEN(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))` to do this for us. (Ideally we could use templates in C++ and prevent people from abusing our macro with pointers but pure C has it's advantages so I won't be one of those "why not use C++?" people.)

Answer (score 1):

1. `sizeof` is good enough for this
2. Matter of taste. I don't use capitals in identifiers at all (unless they are global constants)
3. You can do this:

   ```
   struct foo {
       int   a;
       char  *b;
   } bar;

   bar = (struct foo){0, "Hello"};
   ```
4. To make it explicit, although it is not necessary, if `myFunc` is a function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy values from one struct to another, you can do this:

```
typedef struct {
    int         bar1;
    char*       bar2;
    int (*callback)(int);
} mystruct;

char str[] = "Hello \x45\x10\x00 World!";

int main() { 
  mystruct* foo = (mystruct*)malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
  mystruct* foo2 = (mystruct*)malloc(sizeof(mystruct));
  foo->bar1 = 10;
  foo->bar2 = "hi";

  printf("foo->bar1 = %d, foo->bar2 = %s\n",foo->bar1,foo->bar2);

  memcpy(foo2,foo,sizeof(*foo));

  printf("foo2->bar1 = %d, foo2->bar2 = %s\n",foo2->bar1,foo2->bar2);

  free(foo);
  free(foo2);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
---------- Capture Output ----------
> "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c c:\temp\temp.exe
foo->bar1 = 10, foo->bar2 = hi
foo2->bar1 = 10, foo2->bar2 = hi

> Terminated with exit code 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In general, the number of elements in an array is given by the expression `sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]` (or `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr`).  The `sizeof` operator returns the size of the array in *bytes*, not the number of elements, so you must divide the number of bytes in the array by the number of bytes in an individual element.  However, since `sizeof char == 1` by definition, you can get the number of elements in a char array with just `sizeof arr`.  Note that the expression `arr` must be an *array* type, not a pointer type (for example, if `arr` was passed as a function parameter typed `T arr[]`, then it's a pointer type, and `sizeof` will give you the number of bytes in the pointer, not the array itself).
2. There a number of conventions, none of which are really better than the others.  Which convention you pick doesn't matter as long as you use it consistently.
3. C89 doesn't support compound literals like that.  C99 does, and it should look something like `*foo = (struct s) {0, "Hello, World", myfunc};` (assuming you add a tag `s` to your struct definition).  However, I'm not that familiar with C99 features, so don't take that as gospel.
4. Habit.  In practice it does nothing (a function designator is implicitly converted to a pointer to a function under the usual conversion rules anyway).

Answer (score 0):

2 I use the c# recommendations

If 2 initials then all caps, otherwize only initial cap. Examples

DSPointer, FtpServer, getHDSeekTime, sendSmtpMessage